# How to fix no loaders are configured to process this file. See webpack.js web

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack

I currently facing a problem after i start npm run watch and use this path `src={require('../../../../storage/app/public/'+datas.file)}`, The error shows on my console are. the recommendation says that I need to go here in https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

**Can i ask why this happen after i start the npm run watch?**

```
    WARNING in ./storage/app/public/oiM3JMg4xWttQ7oluBrGuUuenNWIIWNGCUacH509.docx 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '╚' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./storage/app/public sync ^\.\/.*$ ./oiM3JMg4xWttQ7oluBrGuUuenNWIIWNGCUacH509.docx
 @ ./resources/js/components/UserSide/Home.js
 @ ./resources/js/components/App.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./storage/app/public/Deo-Joshua-Crystalynus-O.docx 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '╚' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./storage/app/public sync ^\.\/.*$ ./Deo-Joshua-Crystalynus-O.docx
 @ ./resources/js/components/UserSide/Home.js
 @ ./resources/js/components/App.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./storage/app/public/5be3d06986720.docx 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '╚' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./storage/app/public sync ^\.\/.*$ ./5be3d06986720.docx
 @ ./resources/js/components/UserSide/Home.js
 @ ./resources/js/components/App.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./storage/app/public/5be3d003d6ff6.docx 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '╚' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./storage/app/public sync ^\.\/.*$ ./5be3d003d6ff6.docx
 @ ./resources/js/components/UserSide/Home.js
 @ ./resources/js/components/App.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

WARNING in ./storage/app/public/5be288d563181.docx 1:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '╚' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./storage/app/public sync ^\.\/.*$ ./5be288d563181.docx
 @ ./resources/js/components/UserSide/Home.js
 @ ./resources/js/components/App.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

**My Page that has a warning when I start running my run watch.**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            list_home_data:[],
            list_slider_data:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/get_index_content').then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                list_home_data:response.data[0].get_home_content,
                list_slider_data:response.data[0].get_slider
            })
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));


    }

    renderStoreDirectory() {
        return this.state.list_home_data.map((datas) => {
           if(datas.content_section == 'Store') {
               return (
                    <div key={datas.content_id}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <img alt="example" src={require('./'+datas.file)}  style={{ width:'80%',height:'auto'}} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <h1>{datas.content_title}</h1>
                                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: datas.content}}></p>
                                <a href={datas.link} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Visit Us</a>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
               )
           }
       })
    }

    renderMission() {
        return this.state.list_home_data.map((datas) => {
            if(datas.content_section == 'Mission') {
                return (
                    <div key={datas.content_id}>
                        <h1>{datas.content_title}</h1>
                        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: datas.content}}></p>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
    }

    renderVision() {
        return this.state.list_home_data.map((datas) => {
            if(datas.content_section == 'Vision') {
                return (
                    <div key={datas.content_id}>
                        <h1>{datas.content_title}</h1>
                        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: datas.content}}></p>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        })
    }

    renderCareers() {
        return this.state.list_home_data.map((datas) => {
           if(datas.content_section == 'Career') {
               return (
                    <div key={datas.content_id}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-5">
                                <h1>{datas.content_title}</h1>
                                <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: datas.content}}></p>
                                <a href={datas.link} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">See positions here</a>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <img alt="example" src={require(''+ datas.file)}  style={{ width:'80%',height:'auto'}} />
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
               )
           }
       })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div> 
                <div className="carousel-wrapper">
                    <div id="carouselExampleControls" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div className="carousel-inner">
                            <div className="carousel-item active">
                                <img alt="example" src={require('../../../../assets/1.jpg')} className="d-block w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="carousel-item">
                                <img alt="example" src={require('../../../../assets/2.jpg')} className="d-block w-100"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="carousel-item">
                                <img alt="example" src={require('../../../../assets/3.jpg')} className="d-block w-100"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div className="store-directory-wrapper">
                    <div className="container">
                        {this.renderStoreDirectory()}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="mission-vision-wrapper">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                {this.renderMission()}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                {this.renderVision()}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/><br/>
                <div className="careers-wrapper">
                    <div className="container">
                       <div className="row">
                            {this.renderCareers()}
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> 
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to require a `.docx` file?

Comment: sorry for the late reply Rwd, all type of file, either docx,image,pdf,psd etc

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? Please can you explain why you want to load these files into your javascript, or at least what you're end goal is.

Comment: the goal is, to show the image from database where the image is inside of public storage of laravel folder. the image show properly correct, however in my npm run watch when i Ctrl+S or save there are alot of warning shows like that. I don''t know why it shows warning.

Comment: Ok, well a `docx` file isn't an image, it's a word document. When you `require` a  file with webpack it's going to try and `load` it in to your javascript. To do this, you need to provide a specific loaded so that webpack knows how to `load` this file. Please can you all the code for you component as there is almost definitely a better solution.

Comment: sure .. i will edit my codes that i shared

Comment: hi @Rwd please see the new update. thanks

Comment: Are all of these images publicly accessible? i.e. have you added the symlink for your  public storage folder?

Comment: yes.. i use php artisan storage:link to linked to public. the only problem that i encounter is the warning . like this WARNING in ./storage/app/public/Deo-Joshua-Crystalynus-O.docx 1:2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `require` to pull the file in, you can just set the `src` like you would with plain HTML:

```
src={'/storage/' + datas.file}
```

However, you will still need to perform a check to make sure it's an actual image and not, in this case, a word document.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to initiate

```
yarn run fetch
```

earlier before preparing

```
yarn run start
```